# SQLITE - query integer field based on a bit

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Is there an function, trick, hack to make a query that only retrieves values from a table where an integer field has a special bit set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no function, trick, or hack.
You have to use the [normal operators](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#binaryops) instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE SomeCol & (1 << 5) != 0;
```

Comment: Am I interpreting your example correctly: this query will select all rows where the column `SomeCol` has the fifth bit set? (shifting 1 5 bits left and combine this via a binary AND with the column, meaning this is true, if the 5th bit is set in `SomeCol`)

Comment: Well, `1 << 0` is the zeroth bit then. So, yes.

Comment: So your answer is actually what I was looking for. Did not know that I can do that in a query directly. Do you know if those operators are efficient? Or should I use multiple columns instead if possible?

Comment: That depends on the database schema, the data, the query, the software, and the hardware.